# Select documents in mongoengine but exclude one

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have document retrieved from DB and wat to select any other exclude this one.
I tried following query:

```
{'email': u'test@mail.com', 'id': {'$ne': ObjectId('51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69')}}
{'email': u'test@mail.com', 'pk': {'$ne': ObjectId('51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69')}}

{'email': u'test@mail.com', '_id': {'$ne': ObjectId('51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69')}}
```

Last one is valid query for MongoDB console, the first two - queries I tried to pass to my query object and failed with error message:

```
>>>User.object.query(my_query)

ValidationError: {'$ne': ObjectId('51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69')} is not a valid ObjectId
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Whats the relation to mongoengine?

Comment: @Ross, I am quirying using mongoengine to access database

Comment: Glad you updated your question so it made sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I recon as a reason why the first two queries are not valid is nonexistent fields: `'id'`, `'pk'`. Notice the underscore before the id: `_id`.

In my console, this is a valid query:

```
db.user.find( { 'email' : 'test@mail.com', '_id' : { '$ne' : ObjectId("51d41232ccf2f1a165a92ca6")} } )
```

**EDIT** this is the solution:

### `User.objects.filter(email = 'test@mail.com').filter(id__ne="51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69")`

Longer version

I have tested this with the mongoengine python module, version 0.8.4, so I try to run this line of code:

```
>>>User.object.query(my_query)
```

First of all, the [Document](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document) class does not have `object` attribute, it has `objects`. Second, `objects` a [QuerySet](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet) and it does not have `query` method. What I can do in mongoengine is something like this:

```
>>> res = User.objects.filter(email = 'email51@acme.com')
>>> res[0].email
u'email51@acme.com'
```

And to the point now!. This query will return as the same error:

```
User.objects.filter(email = 'email51@acme.com').filter(id__ne="ObjectId('51d41232ccf2f1a165a92cab')")
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ObjectId('51d41232ccf2f1a165a92cab') is not a valid ObjectId
```

This is the correct way to put it:

```
User.objects.filter(email = 'email51@acme.com').filter(id__ne="51d41232ccf2f1a165a92cab")
```

Comment: I am not asking about mongodb query, but about mongoengine. I is a bit different. As you can see I wrote correct query third.

Answer (score 6):

MongoEngine has its own query syntax that is different to pymongo.

Examples can be seen in the documentation: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html

As @bpgergo mentions you need to convert your query to the correct syntax eg:

```
User.objects.filter(id__ne="51f7f13fca798933a0c70f69", email = 'test@mail.com')
```